# Can a table have two different columns set as primary key ? Given the fact that both the columns have unique and not null values

Tags: sql

If the two columns both have unique values of their own whether it is possible to declare both the columns are primary keys ? PS Not talking about declaring a combination of both the columns as composite key.

Comment: Don't tag spam. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS.

Comment: As for what you appear to be asking, in SQL Server, at least, a table can only have **one** Primary Key. The key *can* contain multiple columns, but you can't define multiple primary keys. If you want other unique columns you want use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`UNIQUE IDNEX`. I doubt that this differs for the other RDBMS you tagged (and that I removed from said tags).

Answer (score 1):

A primary key in a table has three properties:

- The key is `NOT NULL` (all components).
- The key is unique.
- There is only one per table.

This is the definition of a primary key in a relational database.  The third condition makes it pretty clear that you cannot have two of them in the same table.

On the other hand, you could have one primary key and another key that is defined as `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.  You can do this as many times as you like.